# How do I create an XML Intellisense file for my DLL?

Tags: c#, xml, intellisense

I am creating a DLL in C#, using VS 2010, and I have created XML comments for all of its members. When I build the DLL, how do I generate the XML file that will provide Intellisense for the DLL? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the project properties page, go to the Build tab.  In the Output section near the bottom there's a check-box labelled "XML documentation file" that needs to be checked.

Comment: This is odd. If you've gone to all the bother of typing the damn things, why wouldn't you want them bundled with your dlls by default?