# Using a DLL I've created in another VS2010 project doesn't show the intellisense tooltips

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense, tooltip

I've created a DLL to a project in Visual Studio 2010.
I'm using this DLL in another project. Using the functions is completely possible - but I can't see any tooltip.
In addition - if I'm in the same project the tooltips can be seen.

I've read some issues about using the XML file with the name of the DLL in the 2nd project, but I'm afraid I don't have any XML file (as far as I see...).

I'll appreciate your help!
Lior

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an XML Intellisense file for my DLL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893745/how-do-i-create-an-xml-intellisense-file-for-my-dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project settings of your DLL you can specify that a XML file will be created each time the assembly is build. Thi setting is located on the "Build" tab, region "Output" and is called "XML documentation file". Mark the checkbox in front and the xml file will be created.

When you use the dll in another project you have to copy the xml file along with the assembly file to have the IntelliSense information in place.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've also found that answer on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893745/how-do-i-create-an-xml-intellisense-file-for-my-dll

Comment: Thanks for searching *after* asking the question.

Comment: Sorry for that!! :( beginners mistake :)