# How to create NuGet package that includes XML intellisense data

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense, nuget, nuget-package

This link [How do I create an XML Intellisense file for my DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893745/how-do-i-create-an-xml-intellisense-file-for-my-dll) explains how to build your dlls so that an XML file is included containing all your documentation headers so that they are available in those IntelliSense popups.

In my company we frequently distribute our own dlls using an internal NuGet package source. When I create NuGet packages for the package source, how do I ensure that someone else gets the dll from the package source, IntelliSense displays the documentation headers for them?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5205738/284795

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you include Xml Docs for a class library in a NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205738/how-do-you-include-xml-docs-for-a-class-library-in-a-nuget-package)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you distribute your XML files with your *NuGet package* in the same folder as your `Dlls` then  Visual Studio will then find these XML files and show IntelliSense for your assemblies.

To distribute the IntelliSense XML files you will need to add them to your `.nuspec file`, for example:

```XML
<files>
    <file src="bin\IronPython.dll" target="lib\Net40" />
    <file src="bin\IronPython.xml" target="lib\Net40" />
</files>
```

Comment: I'd already tried this. The part I'd missed was that I needed to mention the .xml file in the .nuspec file before creating the package. Can you mention this, and then I'll mark you correct.

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr** documentation files need to be `.xml` not `.XML`

I was able to get the XML files included by first enabling the production using the Build tab, checking XML Documentation File in the Output section.  Note: for some reason I had to manually change the extension from .XML to lowercase .xml. YMMV.  This is the same as the question you referenced, [How do I create an XML Intellisense file for my DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893745/how-do-i-create-an-xml-intellisense-file-for-my-dll).

Once done, I created the Nuspec file in the project directory.  Here's a sample, you can also generate it with `nuget spec MyAssembly.dll` - but make sure to edit it and set the values appropriately.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>Title for your package</title>
    <authors>Package Author</authors>
    <owners>Package Owner</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A description of your library</description>
    <releaseNotes>Release notes for this version.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
    <tags>tag1 tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Once that was done, I used Nuget to package. Note I had to specify the platform because I'm using a 64-bit OS, but I don't have any targets in the project for x64, only AnyCPU

```
nuget pack MyAssembly.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU -build
```

The assembly and it's associated documentation were automatically included in the package.  In addition any packages that you've used in your project are added to the dependency list.

See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package for more information.

Comment: The change uppercase XML to lowercase xml worked for me. Which is sad.